# How to handle HTTP 404 - Page Not Found error using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: http, selenium, header, webdriver, http-status-code-404

I'm testing my web application using Selenium WebDriver by writing script using Java language. Sometimes, I'm getting **HTTP 404 - Page Not Found** message.

How can I handle this error using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you give us more context please? This 404 could have 3 meanings: expected broken link (so 404 is OK), unexpected broken link and the page is really here (so there is a problem in the test), unexpected broken link and the page is not here (so there is a problem in the web app).

Comment: simple "if else" statement will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver cannot track HTTP status/response. You need to use "web debugging proxy" tool like http://www.charlesproxy.com or http://www.fiddler2.com.

You can also track if there is any error by running javascript through the driver. You can compare `document.documentURI === document.location.href` via `execute_script` function. Since `document.documentURI` is overridden by most browsers to display error pages, this will return false in error scenarios.

More on that here - 
http://apoorvparijat.com/selenium-webdriver-doesnt-throw-http-errors/